# Access application context from BundleContextAware class

Tags: spring, osgi, springsource-dm-server

I have created an osgi bundle from an existing legacy war.  The app has a class that implements the spring interface ApplicationContextAware, it then uses the context to programmatically get beans (not sure why but this needs refactoring eventually). The app now uses OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext, but I believe that there is an issue with using this whereby the setApplicationContext method does not get called in any classes implementing ApplicationContextAware, so now the context in this class is always null.

So as a workaround I have implemented BundleContextAware so that I can get a reference to the published context and get access to the beans that way.  This works ok however the only bean on the context is warDeployer (should mention that I am using the spring dm bundle spring-extender to deploy the war).  The bundle present on the context is my bundle so I cannot see why the context that I am getting has none of my beans on it.  The code I have to get the application context is:

ServiceReference ref =  bundleContext.getServiceReference(ApplicationContext.class.getName());
  applicationContext = (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext) bundleContext.getService(ref);

I can see in the logs that much of my context is getting created so I can't see why they are not on the context I am getting.

Can anyone advise as to what is wrong?  I understand that this approach is a bit hacky, but it's temporary until the existing code is refactored.

Thanks in advance.

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the ApplicationContext service is registered asynchronously by the Spring-DM extender. So you probably have a race condition, i.e. asking for the service just before it is actually registered.

You could introduce a delay but then you're very deep into nasty hack territory. It would be better to work out why the `setApplicationContext` method on the `ApplicationContextAware` beans is not being set. You should try raising this is a bug against Spring-DM or asking in the Spring-DM Google Group.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response.  I think that this possibly is a bug as I have not seen any documentation to suggest that this should not work.  There was a jira logged in March this year (https://jira.springframework.org/browse/OSGI-804) but nothing actioned against it.  I have got round the problem by using the BeanFactoryAware interface instead which works ok.  Thanks

Comment: @user521065 .. In case you get this message, can you pls provide some pointers on how you get this issue resolved by using BeanFactoryAware interface ? I replaced ApplicationContextAware with BeanFactoryAware, but still spring is not able to set the factory, resulting a null value.